# How to store unicode encoded string (JSON) in database?

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli, unicode

In my web app I need to store JSON in one of the database fields (just one field). On the backend side (PHP) I am converting array to json via `json_encode()`.

The output of the above is:

```
[{"przyczyna":"Niezgodno\u015b\u0107"}]
```

Which is encoded:

```
[{"przyczyna":"Niezgodność"}]
```

And this is correct.

Then I am sending this string to my database via `mysqli` (standard `$mysqli->query()`).

And when I go to my database I can see that the field has value:

```
[{"przyczyna":"Niezgodnou015bu0107"}]
```

The backslashes are gone and I can't properly decode it. How can I upload this to my database without backslashed being stripped? On the PHP side and database (`MySQL`) I am using `utf8` coding. I tried to use `utf8mb4` but the result was the same.

Comment: json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) add following in your code.

Comment: @RahulSingh then I got `[{"przyczyna":"Niezgodno??"}]`

Comment: [{"przyczyna":"Niezgodność"}] your string is in utf-8 format inorder to store utf-8 string in your mysql DB. You can refer  following links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441418/cannot-store-utf8-characters-in-mysql and http://jonisalonen.com/2012/ultimate-guide-to-utf8-and-mysql/

Comment: I need special characters to be encoded like this `\uXXX` because I am decoding JSON in javascript.

Comment: you may try this mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8"); this will work for unicode also and try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331883/utf-8-php-and-mysqli-utf8 and have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: @RahulSingh I am using `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');`

Comment: The backslashes went away because you failed to escape the string before calling `query()`.  That is always needed, and is independent of the use of json.

Comment: @RickJames: yes that's right. I needed to add `addslashes()` after `json_encode()` but for some reasons moderators on stackoverflow removed my answer.